# Console.log in Firefox does not show actual object value. Why?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, object, firefox, console.log

I recently switched to the Firefox Developer Edition and I like it quite a lot. There is just one thing that bothers me: sometimes the logging of objects in the console is just not readable.

An example:
I log this

```
console.log('postFilterBySlug: ', postFilterBySlug)
```

Where postFilterBySlug is structured like this:

postFilterBySlug:

```
{
    activeFilter: false,
    isCoPage: false
}
```

In Firefox I will get this:

[image: Console Log in Firefox]

Whereas in Chrome I get this, which is actually what I want to see:

[image: Console Log in Chrome]

Am I missing something? Can I somehow get Firefox to show me the actual values? And what would be the advantage of what Firefox does?

Thanks a lot for some input.

---

Edit:
Same again: I really tried to dig to reveal the project's title with Firefox:
[image: Every indentation is a click...]
But I cannot reveal the value itself.

While with chrome:
[image: All neat and tidy]

No way to change this behaviour? I really like firefox but for this kind of logging it is really annoying...

Comment: what type of object is it? Are you using a framework? It looks like an observable. Or at least an object that has inherited some prototype methods.

Comment: what are you talking about? they're both showing the same thing but in firefox you have the some of the properties open. click the down arrows on the left to close them and both will look the same. firefox does not change your object in any way nor does it show you things that arean't there.

Comment: @Occam'sRazor Yeah I know that I have properties open. I did this on purpose to show you how it looks like. But where would I click on the firefox's version to actually reveal the value "events" of `activeFilter`? That's my question. I opened a lot of those arrows, but I did nowhere find the actual values... (and yes what you say is right (no changes, and no things that are not there), but so far it seems that Firefox is not showing me something that should be there...)

Comment: @floor It is a variable set in the vuex store (vue.js). And I guess it has to be watched at all times to changes on to components who use the variable. Although I have to say I don't know the details about whats's going on under the hood of vue and vuex.

Comment: @Merc it looks like its correct in firefox because the getter and setter is a function and to get that value you need to call the get function for the property. They both show it correctly, chrome just doesn't make you dig for the value. If you toggle open more properties in firefox I think you will find the value.

Comment: @floor Digging did not help :(. (See images above) and I somehow cannot call the get function to show all the properties (which all have a getter/setter), right?

Comment: @Merc its hard to say, if you create a demo that has a the same issue I can check it later

Comment: I have the same issue, trying to see an Object's values bring printed on click, using vue.js. In chrome the values get printed nicely, in firefox I get all these nested properties that I don't need. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @EdgarQuintero Nope so far I did not. It seems to me that Firefox just handles this case differently... ‍♂️

Comment: Ok.... for now I'm using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` very annoying having to type this out every single time but oh well!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if there's a better answer, but for now I'm using:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)));
```

Comment: Ok, I normally find it easier to open chrome... :D

Comment: not a matter of browser, it is happening with Chrome too :) Edgar, can you explain your answer ? It works but I would like to know why ?

Comment: Annoying to use like that in order to not open milion arrows. and better use `console.dir` instead of log